# Rust Git2 - How to specify the branch type to pull all (new) branches

Tags: rust, git2-rs

After I cloned a git repo, I'm trying to keep it up to date by fetching and merging all new branches.

I have successfully cloned the repo but I can't seem to get all the branches to sync.

I found the `.branches()` that seems to go and fetch all branches names and `.next` or `.collect` that allows you to go through the returned results. I also saw that the value for the `branches()` method are either `Local` or `Remote`, if I read this correctly: https://docs.rs/git2/latest/src/git2/lib.rs.html#365-370

Now, I can't seem to figure out *how* to use `.branches`. Here's the code and output.

When I try:

```
let remote_name = "origin";
let repo = Repository::open(".").unwrap();
let mut remote = repo.find_remote(remote_name).expect("Can't find remote");
let br = repo.branches("Remote");
```

I get:

```
expected `Option<BranchType>`, found `&str`
```

So I try this:

```
let br = repo.branches(Some("Remote"));
```

and I get:

```
expected `BranchType`, found `&str`
```

I also tried:

```
let br = repo.branches(remote);
```

Which gives:

```
expected `Option<BranchType>`, found `Option<&str>`
```

So I'm kind of confused as to how to format it to pass the value correctly. I've tried with `[]` without luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`"Remote"` is a string, you need to use the value `Remote` of the `BranchType` enum instead:

```
let br = repo.branches(Some(BranchType::Remote));
```

See: https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch06-01-defining-an-enum.html#enum-values

Answer (score -2):

thi wil work

> let br = repo.branches(Some(BranchType::Remote));

here you can find more information:  https://doc.rust-lang.org/book

Comment: Please remove this answer as it is a copy of the accepted one.